# Type inference with functional builders

Tags: kotlin, type-inference

I'm using Kotlin [KBuilders](http://levelmoney.github.io/kbuilders/) with some protobuffs and have run into a situation that is confusing me.

To start off, I have a function that takes a file name and list of serialized JSON and deserialized that JSON to a protobuff.

```
fun parseFileData(fileName: String, lines: List<String>): Data.Builder.() -> Unit = when (fileName) {
        SOME_FILE_NAME -> deserializeLinesToModel(lines, DataModel::class.java)
                .let {
                    return {
                        dataMeasurement = buildDataMeasurement {
                            property1 = it.reduce { acc, n -> acc + n }
                            measurementMsec = it.map { it.measurementMsec }
                        }
                    }
                }
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException()
```

The first thing I didn't understand was why I needed the return inside the let block. But it worked so I moved on.

I later decided to refactor some stuff to make code elsewhere simpler and ended up with something like this:

```
fun parseFileData(fileName: String, factory: DataFactory): Sequence<Data.Builder.() -> Unit> = when (fileName) {
        SOME_FILE_NAME -> factory.getSomeFileSequence() // returns Sequence<Model>
                                .batch(1000) // process data in batches of 1000 to reduce memory footprint and payload size 
                                .map { return {
                                            dataMeasurement = buildDataMeasurement {
                                            property1 = it.reduce { acc, n -> acc + n }
                                            measurementMsec = it.map { it.measurementMsec }
                                    }
                                }
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException()
```

So basically, instead of processes each batch as a list, I read the sequence from the factory, batch it into a sequence of lists and try to map each list to a `Data.Builder.() -> Unit`. However, this time I get `return is not allowed here`. I've tried multiple variations, with and without return and map and let and whatnot. The closest I've gotten to is a return type of Sequence<() -> Unit> which fails type inference.

Can anyone explain what's going on here? And why this type cannot be inferred?

Comment: Does you read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html ?
In second case latest expression in map block (lambda) is return value. In first case you have so called "non-local return" https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns

Comment: I am unable to refactor your code without specifying all the types and functions. How about publishing a link to you code base?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I can not share the code base. I'll try to write up the relevant code in a self-contained class when I have time.

Answer (score 2):

`return` in the `map` lambda is a non-local return. It tries to return from the closest `fun` function, which happens to be `parseFileData`.

Non-local returns are only allowed from inline functions, whose lambda parameters are inlined at the call site, and the `map` extension for `Sequence` is not an inline function.

If you want to return a value from the lambda itself, use [qualified return](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels) `return@map ...`, or omit it completely: then the last expression in the block will be returned as the result.